# imperative loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to understand the monad system in Haskell. About 80% of my previous programming experiance is in C, but ironically the imperative part of Haskell is the hardest to understand. List manipulation and lazy evaluation was much more clear. Anyway I want to make ghc accept this code. I know the code doesn't make sense at all. Most obviously, I'm passing a `Bool` where `IO Bool` is expected. But that's not the only problem. I know this is a stupid question, but please help me to further my understanding of the Haskell language.

```
import Control.Monad

while :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
while cond action = do
  c <- cond
  when c $ do
    action
    while cond action

main :: IO ()
main = do
  i <- 0
  while (i < 10) $ do
    i <- i + 1
    print i
```

---

Here's how I finally did it. I know `allocaArray` isn't necessary, but it was very fun to use. Haskell really has no limits, very powerful.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

while :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
while cond action = do
  c <- cond
  if c then do
    action
    while cond action
  else return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let n = 10
  allocaArray n $ \p -> do
    i <- newIORef 0
    while (liftM (< n) (readIORef i)) $ do
      i2 <- readIORef i
      poke (advancePtr p i2) i2
      modifyIORef i (+ 1)
    writeIORef i 0
    while (liftM (< n) (readIORef i)) $ do
      i2 <- readIORef i
      (peek $ advancePtr p i2) >>= print
      modifyIORef i (+ 1)
```

Comment: Let's start with the obvious. `i` is not a mutable variable, and doesn't become one simply because you have a monad around. `i <- i + 1` refers to two different `i`s.

Comment: The `while` construction is rather rarely used in Haskell, I think precisely because in Haskell it doesn't actually allow you to use "variables" in a natural way for people used to imperative languages. You *can* do the same thing more awkwardly, but you have to use mutable references such as those in `Data.IORef` or `Control.Concurrent.MVar`. Unless you really need mutable update, it's generally better to express it functionally.

Comment: Note that using an `IORef` in this manner leads to the loop counter being "boxed", so a new `Int` box will be allocated on each iteration and accessing the counter involves pointer indirection. When you deal with a more functional-style counter, GHC can usually unbox it, leading to faster code.

Comment: Also, why are you using all that `Foreign` stuff? Do you actually need to deal with foreign code? Do you have a reason to make the garbage collector treat the array as foreign? If not, you should consider using unboxed mutable vectors (from the `vector` package) instead.

Comment: There are also libraries that offer unboxed mutable variables; I don't know how well they perform. The basic idea is to use a mutable byte array to store a "variable".

Comment: @dfeuer `allocaArray` will just move the stack pointer while `Data.Vector` should go through the garbage collector. That's one reason. The code here by the way is just an experiment to write almost C in Haskell, while learning about monads.

Comment: @xiver77 that's not correct. `allocaArray` allocates on the heap and is subject to garbage collection, although it's never moved, so that it can be passed to foreign code. `Vector` can be moved, but allocating it isn't slower, and heap allocation in GHC is not much slower than stack allocation anyway. For pure Haskell purposes `Vector` is better since pinned arrays might cause memory fragmentation.

Comment: Just wanted to say that copying C/imperative habits and idioms to Haskell is probably the worst possible way to start learning it. Wait with mutables until you're more fluent in proper idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: @n.m. That is really your personal opinion. I'm not arguing that writing imperative style code everywhere in Haskell is good. But writing immutable, functional style code doesn't solve every problem, or more exactly it isn't well suited for every problem. You eventually have to deal with monads and mutable, imperative patterns, which Haskell supports well in a well-designed, organized manner. I'm just starting to learn about those, and the answers to this question helped me a lot. Don't force your ideas with words such as 'probably the worst possible' or 'proper idiomatic'.

Comment: "it isn't well suited for every problem" --- that's true. "You eventually have to deal with monads and mutable" --- you do, the operative word being *eventually*. If you start applying imperative patterns early on, without having a good understanding of functional patterns, you are putting the cart before the horse. But that's your choice of course.

Comment: @n.m. Did I say anywhere in this post that I do not have good understanding in the functional patterns? I rather said "list manipulation and lazy evaluation was much more clear". The basic Haskell book I have called "Programming in Haskell" use monads just for console IO.

Comment: I did choose words poorly; rather than "imperative" I should have said "with global mutable state". Monads and local state are perfectly OK; learn them and use them from early on. See my answer for one such solution. I haven't thought of monads and local state as imperative when I wrote my comments.

Comment: [Here](http://conscientiousprogrammer.com/blog/2015/12/11/24-days-of-hackage-2015-day-11-monad-loops-avoiding-writing-recursive-functions-by-refactoring/) is great article about Monadic Loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things which keep your code from typechecking:

1. Your `while` function expects an `IO Bool` but you give it `i < 10` which is an expression of type `Bool`. To turn a `Bool` into `IO Bool`, simply use `return`.
2. When you write `i <- 0` you try to use the literal zero as a monadic value, which it isn't. Remember that

   ```
   main = do
       i <- 0
       ...
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   main = 0 >>= \i -> do ...
   ```

To fix this, you could also promote the `0` via `return`.

Hence, you end up with

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    i <- return 0
    while (return (i < 10)) $ do
        i <- return (i + 1)
        print i
```

However, this still won't do what you intend to do: the reason is that the first (leftmost) `i` in `i <- return (i + 1)` is *different* than the `i` in `i <- return 0`. You're *shadowing* the variable, creating a new variable with the same name, which you then print. So you don't actually bump any counter at all.

I don't want to spoil the fun, but if you really get stuck: there's a [`monad-loops`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package which exposes a couple of useful monadic loop functions, including a [`whileM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:whileM) function.

Comment: The `while` in the OP is pretty much equivalent to that package's `whileM_` (slightly less general type but not importantly); I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: There are some other loopy libraries around, such as [`loops`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loops) and [`control-monad-loop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-loop), that offer facilities better aligned with the OP's desires. `monad-loops` has some cool concurrency tools, but otherwise it seems less general.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with this approach is that `i` is not a mutable variable. You could use `IORef`, however a more functional approach would be to pass the current state through each iteration. You could rewrite your `whileM` body and conditions to take the current value:

```
whileM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m ()
whileM test act init =
   when (test init) $ (act init) >>= whileM test act
```

then you can do

```
whileM (< 10) (\i -> print i >> return (i + 1)) 0
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution with local state (State and the associated monad transformer), as opposed to global state (`IORef` and friends):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

while :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
while cond action = do
  c <- cond
  when c $ do
    action
    while cond action

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  runStateT (while cond body) 1 
  return ()

body :: StateT Integer IO ()
body = do
    x <- get
    liftIO $ print x
    put (x + 1)
    return ()

cond :: StateT Integer IO Bool
cond = do
    x <- get
    return (x < 10)
```

Loop body and loop condition are explicit and named for clarity; it's possible to write e.g. `while (liftM (< 10) get) body`.